# Is it possible to get all the MKAnnotationViews added to the mainMapView?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, mkmapview

I am implementing a MKMapView based application. In that I need to get all the annotations from the mapview. Is it possible to get all the MKAnnotationViews added to the mainMapView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/annotations